# Can anyone provide me Magento2 Documents that from where i can learn to develop modules for Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento2 but have experience in Magento. But found that structure of Magento2 is completly different. So can anyone provide me magento2 document that how to create module in Magento2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the very basic, a new Magento2 module requires three files.

```
 /etc/module.xml
 composer.json
 registration.php
```

I have always created my modules in the `/app/code` folder, in which case you would create a Vendor folder (using a name of your choosing) and then within that a Module folder (again, with a name of your choosing). For example, the full path would be `/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName`.

Within the module folder, add one additional folder called `/etc`.

With the folder structure created, you simply need to add the contents of the three files, replacing VendorName and ModuleName with the names you set above.

**/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="0.1.0" />
</config>
```

**/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "vendorname/module-modulename",
    "description": "",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "license": [],
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.0",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "VendorName/ModuleName"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

With those three files in place, the final step is to register the module with Magento by running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` on the command line in the root of your Magento installation.

After that, you should see your module listed in `bin/magento module:status` or "Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced" on the backend.

From there you can start adding Controllers, Models, Observers, Plugins, etc. A quick web search should surface a bunch of tutorials for creating more useful modules, but you should certainly visit the [official Magento2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/intro/developers_roadmap.html) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

```
Module_Name
folder:-    controller
      adminhtml
         AllNews
           Index.php
folder:-    etc
      adminhtml
      Module.xml
folder:-    view
             layout
               Module_Name_allnews_index.xml
             templates
               allnews.phtml
    composer.json
    registration.php
```